# FullCalendar events showing up as current time rather than their actual start time

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm tyring to display events in [fullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) via a [JSON feed](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) and it keeps showing the events under the current time rather than the times provided via the feed:

```
function getAvailableDates() {
  $("#availabilitySchedule").fullCalendar({ 

    events: {
      url: window.location.href + '/available_dates',
      type: 'GET', 
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {
        startParam: 'availability_start',
        endParam: 'availability_end',
        allDay: false,
      }
    },

    allDaySlot: false,
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    editable: false,
    droppable: false,
    unselectAuto: true,
    timezone: 'local',
  });
}
```

Here is what my JSON feed looks like:

```
[{"id":20,"professional_id":49,"availability_start":"2015-01-29T14:18:00.000Z","availability_end":"2015-01-29T21:18:00.000Z","recurrances":"single","created_at":"2015-01-28T21:18:38.000Z","updated_at":"2015-01-28T21:18:38.000Z"}]
```

Any idea what may be causing this to happen?

Comment: I think `startParam` and `endParam` only affect the query string parameter names passed to the server and have no effect on what event properties it uses to render the calendar.

Comment: I also tried just using start: / end: as well as "start"/"end" and still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so it looks I was able to find my answer [here](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2014/11/transform-json-field-names-in-feed-to.html). Here's what I have now, which seems to be working fine for me now:

```
events: function (start, end) {
      $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href + '/available_dates',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var events = [];
            $.each(data, function (index) {
              events.push({
                "start": data[index].availability_start,
                "end": data[index].availability_end
              });
            });
          callback(events);
        },
        error: function () { alert('Oh no!'); },
      });
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. You could also use this method http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/ . Same thing but less "custom" than your method.